# Struggling to pull in extensions to a visualforce page based on an apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am creating a visualforce page to pull data from my main object (Taskray_Project_c) and that all renders nicely onto my visualforce page. However now i want to add in some data from related objects (Taskray__trContributor__c).

I have written the Apex Class which passes with 83% code coverage

But when i try to reference my Table in the visualforce page (lines 20-24) it fails and cannot find any rows for assignment.

I am a bit new to all this and have taken the majority of the code from other pieces of work i have found but it all seemed to work until i tried referencing the other object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query on line number 9 is obselete. As your standard controller is already on `TASKRAY_Project__c`, you do not need to query it again.

So to retrieve related contributers of project, you would need to modify the query filter on line number 11 from:

```
WHERE Id =: trc.TASKRAY_Project__c
```

to:

```
WHERE TASKRAY_Project__c =: std.getRecord().Id
```

Comment: Hi Rahul - thanks for that - i am now getting an error msg - my code is

public class contributers
{
    public List<TASKRAY__trContributor__c> con { get; set; }
    
    Public contributers( ApexPages.StandardController std )
    {
        if( std.getRecord().Id != null )
        {
            con = [ Select Id, TASKRAY__User__c, Project_Contribution_Days__c, Contributor_Role__c,TASKRAY__Project__c from TASKRAY__trContributor__c where TASKRAY_Project__c =: str.getRecord().Id ];
        }
        else
        {
            con = new List<TASKRAY__trContributor__c>(); }}}

Comment: Hi Rahul sorry i have uploaded my new error message above,

Comment: My bad it was a typo: `std.getRecord().Id`, updated answer as well!

Comment: Rahul you are a star!!! thank you so much

I may now be able to relax and enjoy my weekend!!

Comment: Cheers, happy weekend and learning!